# How can I solve it with barplot?

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have a data_1 like this:

```
percentile      max_border
0.1         42
0.2         92
0.3         134
0.4         177
0.5         219
0.6         268
0.7             312
0.8         382
0.9         466
1.0         714
```

And a barplot:

[image]

How can I add information from data*1 (max*border) to each column?

data_2

```
percentile  quantity
0   0.2 9217
1   0.7 9245
2   1.0 9257
3   0.6 9295
4   0.3 9325
5   0.8 9332
6   0.4 9380
7   0.9 9382
8   0.5 9414
9   0.1 9511
```

```
r_plot = sns.barplot(data=data_2, y='quantity', x='percentile')
```

The expect result is as follows:

[image]